# How to have infinite width for right scrolling game

Tags: android, andengine

I am a newbie to game development and currently using AndEngine for an android game. It is a right scrolling game where the player can continuously move to right of the screen like mario.

How can we have infinite right scrolling?

Currently, I am setting my boundCamera Limits like this:

```
 camera.setBounds(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH*100,  CAMERA_HEIGHT);
```

and I create a frame like this:

public void createFrame(){

```
//  205-175-149     cdaf95
final IAreaShape/*Shape*/ ground = new Rectangle(0, mCameraHeight - 2, mCameraWidth*100, 2, gameLogicController.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
ground.setColor(0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f);
final IAreaShape/*Shape*/ roof = new Rectangle(0, 0, mCameraWidth*100, 2, gameLogicController.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
roof.setColor(0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f);
final IAreaShape/*Shape*/ left = new Rectangle(0, 0, 2, mCameraHeight, gameLogicController.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
left.setColor(0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f);
final IAreaShape/*Shape*/ right = new Rectangle(mCameraWidth*100 - 2, 0, 2, mCameraHeight, gameLogicController.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
right.setColor(0.7f, 0.5f, 0.3f);

final FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, ground, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, roof, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, left, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, right, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);


scene.attachChild(ground);
scene.attachChild(roof); 
scene.attachChild(left); 
scene.attachChild(right);
```

}

But it ends up being fixed width only (100 times camera width). How can I have infinite width? If I give very large value, app crashes.

Thank you for any help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont want the width to be infinite because then the game will never finish loading. Instead of having a fixed background manipulate it to appear as if the background is moving.

Comment: I am using parallax background. So, my background is moving. I wanted to understand, how games like mario are designed. Do they have fixed width?

Comment: @Sushil Levels in the Mario games certainly have a fixed width.

Comment: @Kabuko.. So it means that they have parallax background and add goodies and obstacles at runtime to give a moving effect?

Comment: games in Mario do have a fixed with but he said an infinite background, meaning the world is limitless.